Deprecation of "textsize" method in PIL
Good day, i am working on a project where i create a lot of PDFs and have been away for about half a year due to my work. Now I came back and should work a bit further on my project but I ran into some issues regarding deprecated functions in Pillow.
Here is the Function I have problems with:
def text(self, x, y, text, color, font_size, font_name=IRRELEVANT_FONT_REGULAR):
        """ draws centralized text """
        font = ImageFont.truetype(font_name, font_size) # which font to use
        w, h = self.draw.textsize(text, font=font) # width, height of text for alignment
        self.draw.text(((x - 0.5 * w), (y - 0.5 * h)), text, color, font=font, align="center") # draws text

As you can see, it uses the "textsize" method which is deprecated since version 9.3.0 of Pillow.
I am running into errors when creating the PDFs because of this function and do not know how to work around this to be honest since I did not write the code myself and am just expanding the code as the project gets bigger.
I tried to change the textsize method out with the textlength method, getsize method (which I found out is also deprecated).
Does anybody know any workaround or replacement for the textsize method?

It's no longer called textsize, it's called textlength.

i tried texlength but it gave me this error:
w, h = self.draw.textlength(text, font=font) # width, height of text for alignment
    ^^^^
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object

